# Send Query Parameters to Actor through path

Tags: akka.net

I would like to use the path of an Actor as a dynamic webhook, something like:

`foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose`

Is it possible to pass parameters to an actor reference based on the path?

Somehow querying for actor `foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose`, would return `foo://example.com:8042/over/there` with some `?name=ferret#nose` context.

If this is not possible, is there a way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. Akka uses URI formatting to describe actors hierarchy and to locate them, but it's not customizable by programmers in any way beside choosing names for actor system and its actors.